# Trying to divide rownames by the character '_'

Tags: dataframe, split

Morning everyone,
I'm new in this community,
I'm working in RStudio and my question is this:
I have a data frame (with the name of some genes) where the columns are joined by this character '_':

```
               Sample_01
BGN_BGN        1.0000000  
RPS4Y1_BGN    -0.2367307  
COMP_BGN       0.2664066 
COL2A1_BGN     0.2746505  
LOC653219_BGN -0.2651348 
XAGE1_BGN     -0.2604609
```

I want to divide the names of the genes, and these genes should be in a different column where corresponds, for example: column 1(gen1) - column 2(gen2) - column 3(Sample_01).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the language in use?

Comment: Sorry the language is R, I'm working on Rstudio

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.